# Python Pandas using count, drop_duplicates to get the difference of pre-duplicate dropped column count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a script to pull a csv file with ~3 million rows of data and narrowing down the columns as i read and save it. I am using the following to count col1 as follows:

My data from col1 is ip addresses

```
print('total count for: ' + str(df['col1'].count()))
```

Then using the below code to drop duplicates from this same column from the next line of code.

```
print(df.col1.duplicated(keep="first").count())
```

I am now attempting to find the difference between the above. Meaning that I have a .count pre-duplicated of 2368 and after the duplicated I get 2349. I am trying to subtract 2368 from 2349 and print that value.

I have tried multiple variations of .count - .duplicated with no luck. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.duplicated()` method just returns a boolean Series of the same size as the size of the original column, with `True` values in rows where values are duplicate.  Running `count()` on that column will still produce the same number of rows as the original count.

You could replace it with the `drop_duplicates(keep='first')` method to actually remove the duplicates:

`print(df['col1'].count() - df['col1'].drop_duplicates(keep='first').count())`

To simplify, you could just run this expression to get the same value, as it will sum up `True` values to get you the number of rows with duplicate values:

`print(df.col1.duplicated(keep="first").sum())`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the additional info around .duplicated and drop_duplicates as well.